# Equality about function which returns the sum of the unique prime factors?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

I recently had an idea and derived some formulas through elementary means. Let, 
$F(x)$ be an function which returns the sum of the unique prime factors of $x$. $\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}$. $\lambda(x)$ return the number of unique primes.

For example,

$$ F(12) = 2 + 3 = 5$$
$$ \lambda(12) = 1+ 1 =2$$

Let, $p_i$ be the $i$'th prime and $\floor{x} $ be the floor function. Then,

$$ \sum_{p_k < p_1p_2\dots p_n} p_k \floor{\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p_i}{p_k}}  = \sum_{r=2}^{p_1 p_2\dots p_n} F(r)$$

Using similar means:

$$ \sum_{p_k < (p_1p_2\dots p_n)^2} \floor{\frac{(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i)^2}{p_k}}  = \sum_{r=2}^{(p_1 p_2\dots p_n)^2} \lambda(r)$$

### Question

Is it possible to improve upon the formulas by introducing some error?

Comment: why do you need the floor function? As far as I can see you have $(\Pi_{i = 1}^np_i) / p_k = \Pi_{i = 1, i \neq k}^np_i$.

Comment: @araomis let $n=2$ then $p_k$ can also be $p_3 = 5$. Then I need the floor function ..

Comment: Ah thanks. That's what I missed.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What would you consider an improvement? And why would you think that introducing error to an exact equation would improve it?

Comment: Well, for example after googling a bit I learned that the primorial has a nice asymptotic formula ... I was hoping to get the R.H.S as some asymptotic formula ....